# In Qt's QMake pro files, how can I differentiate between android for 32-bit arm and android for 64-bit arm?

Tags: qt, qmake

In a Qt `.pro` file, I can distinguish between android and windows like:

```
linux:android {
  LIBS += -L[...]
}

win32 {
  LIBS += -L[...]
}
```

How can I distinguish between `android` for 32-bit ARM platform aka armeabi7v and anddroid 64-bit ARM aka aarch64.

How can I specify `aarch64` or `armeabi7v` in the pro file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently `QT_ARCH` tells me more, which leads to:

```
android:contains(QT_ARCH, arm) {
  message("arm32!");
}

android:contains(QT_ARCH, arm64) {
  message("arm64!");
}
```